# How should we go about implementing AsyncResponseConsumer for HttpAsyncClient in Apache HTTPClient5 implementation?

Tags: http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpclient-5.x

The interface of HTTPAsyncClient has changed in HTTPClient5 implementation as following:

```java
  public interface HttpAsyncClient {

    /**
     * Initiates asynchronous HTTP request execution using the given context.
     * <p>
     * The request producer passed to this method will be used to generate
     * a request message and stream out its content without buffering it
     * in memory. The response consumer passed to this method will be used
     * to process a response message without buffering its content in memory.
     * <p>
     * Please note it may be unsafe to interact with the context instance
     * while the request is still being executed.
     *
     * @param <T> the result type of request execution.
     * @param requestProducer request producer callback.
     * @param responseConsumer response consumer callback.
     * @param pushHandlerFactory the push handler factory. Optional and may be {@code null}.
     * @param context HTTP context. Optional and may be {@code null}.
     * @param callback future callback. Optional and may be {@code null}.
     * @return future representing pending completion of the operation.
     */
    <T> Future<T> execute(
            AsyncRequestProducer requestProducer,
            AsyncResponseConsumer<T> responseConsumer,
            HandlerFactory<AsyncPushConsumer> pushHandlerFactory,
            HttpContext context,
            FutureCallback<T> callback);

}
```

What I want to have is that after calling execute on the client, I get an HTTPResponse object in the callback and then I invoke my own deserializer on it. Will this work now? I want to support both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.

I could find a builder for AsyncRequestProducer but I'm not sure of how to implement the AsyncReponseConsumer and more so which implementations to choose from? and what is the impact and difference?
There are a few like

1. AbstractBinResponseConsumer
2. AbstractCharResponseConsumer
3. BasicResponseConsumer
4. SimpleResponseConsumer

I could also find a [factory](https://github.com/ok2c/httpcomponents-jackson/blob/1ae2393df58cedbca3f560fd7c5688bf9f4e525d/hc5-async-json/src/main/java/com/ok2c/hc5/json/http/JsonResponseConsumers.java) for AsyncResponseConsumer inside

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ok2c.hc5</groupId>
    <artifactId>hc5-async-json</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope someone would be able to clear what all of these are and when should what be used? I wanted to understand the impact before implementing anything.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

1. Disregard `Basic*` and `Simple*` variety of implementations. They are intended for most basic, simple cases where message content is known to be small (<100KiB)
2. Extend `AbstractCharAsyncEntityConsumer` or `AbstractCharResponseConsumer` if you are processing text messages
3. Extend `AbstractBinAsyncEntityConsumer` or `AbstractBinResponseConsumer` if you are processing binary messages
4. Extend `AbstractClassicEntityConsumer` or `AbstractClassicServerExchangeHandler` if really have to use some classic (`InputStream` / `OutputStream`) based message handling code and delegate message processing to a pool of worker threads
5. Use `hc5-async-json` if you want to process JSON messages in a fully asynchronous, event-driven mode

Comment: Hi @ok2c, Can you please share some examples of where these are used? 
Also, do we need to create separate async request producers and consumers every time we make a request with httpAyncClient.execute(), or do we need to somehow reuse them? and with this implementation how is the TCP connection being reused. For instance, when I make calls like https://resource/a, https://resource/b, https://resource/c?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/5.1.x/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/AsyncClientHttpExchangeStreaming.java

Comment: Can SimpleResponseConsumer be used for content size more than 100KiB? In your earlier reply, you suggested to disregard Basic* and Simple* variety of implementations. They are intended for most basic, simple cases where message content is known to be small (<100KiB)



What would be the behavior if SimpleResponseConsumer is used for content size more than 100KiB?



Looking into the code of SimpleResponseConsumer, looks like it can work with any data size though this would be slow when data is more than 1024 bytes.

Comment: @SrijanSrivastav There is no limit in size the Basic* and Simple* can handle, and I think the 100KiB was just a guideline. However, with these two implementations, the whole body will be allocated in memory (in a byte array or a String). For large bodies, this will lead to massive arrays allocations on the heap and may lead to performance issues.